# How to filter on dictionnary to autocomplete a form?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a users list on "Database" sheet:
[image]

On "Form" sheet, assistants fill out a specific user list from "Database" data.
[image]

How to search on DATABASE sheet to autocomplete "Form" sheet when assistant typing a key-word (for example ID) ?

For example: If assistant, typing ID=1546, i would like LastNAme and First Name autocomplete with LastNAme= Aalderink and First Name= Darell.

I don't know how I do that. I using cascading drop-down list, but assistant must always start by "LastName"

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to make use of [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) function. This function can give you another value from a "table" given a key, in this case `ID` which needs to be the first column of that table.

So, on your sheet `DATABASE` I would change the `ID` column to be in column `A`, `Last Name` on `B` and `First Name` on `C`.
Then on sheet `Form` I would put this formula in cell `A2`

`=IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2;DATABASE!$A$2:$C$17;2;FALSE);"")`

and in cell `B2`

`=IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2;DATABASE!$A$2:$C$17;3;FALSE);"")`

Finally simply drag the formula to the cells you required. The [`IFNA`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFNA-function-6626c961-a569-42fc-a49d-79b4951fd461) function is just to prevent the cases where no match is performed. I made the output blank (`""`) but you can change it for any value, e.g. `"No match!"`

**Note:** I would also suggest you to make use of [defined names](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64) in order to avoid always being redefining the database range. That way you just need to write something like:

`=IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2;table_data;2;FALSE);"No match!")`

HTH ;)

Comment: With your method, user must always start by "ID". i would like sometthings more flexible. I think i will do a Search box where user typing ID OR FirstName OR LastName then select correct line to add in Form sheet. But  I don't know how I do that

Comment: Ok @Ferfa, but how will you handle the cases where you have Mary Jane 123 and Jane Saint 456? Since there is Jane in first name and last name which user would you choose? (That's why I was using the ID as the search parameter since it should be unique)